# GRUB failed to install

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I believe this problem originated when I tried to run an apt upgrade. When I ran the upgrade, I got a bright pink screen that says that:

```
GRUB failed to install to the following devices:
/dev/nvme0n1p1
```

followed by a warning that if I continue anyways my computer may not start up properly.

Selecting no on that prompt brings me to an option for what EFI partitions I want grub-install to automatically run for. The options are:

```
[ ] /dev/sda3 (537 MB; ) on 4000787 MB WDC_WD40EZRZ-00GXCB0
[*] /dev/nvme0n1p1 (104 MB; /boot/efi) on 1000204 MB Samsung...
```

By default, only the second one is selected. Selecting enter here just brings me back to the first screen.

Here is the output of a few commands that seem relevant:

```
$lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   2.9T  0 part /media/stuart/Vault
├─sda3        8:3    0   513M  0 part 
└─sda4        8:4    0 795.8G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 784.4G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   505M  0 part


$sudo parted -l
    Model: ATA WDC WD40EZRZ-00G (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      16.8MB  3146GB  3146GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 3      3146GB  3146GB  538MB   fat32        EFI System Partition          boot, esp
 4      3146GB  4001GB  855GB   ext4


Model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 1TB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   123MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   842GB   842GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      1000GB  1000GB  530MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag

$efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,545bfbfa-d84a-43d4-a467-41e4141a299e,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...M................
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,545bfbfa-d84a-43d4-a467-41e4141a299e,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
```

Closing the window leads to an interrupted dpkg, which it prompts me to manually configure. manually configuring dpkg leads to the GRUB install loop.

I am dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

Comment: Is Windows fast start up on? Or did a Windows update turn it back on? Your NVMe partition looks like the correct place to install grub for UEFI system. Do you have an Ubuntu live installer for new version. You can then reinstall grub using that either manually or with Boot-Repair. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I found my live installer and booted into that, and downloaded and ran Boot-Repair.  Here is the link to the result: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5pBs8yDwFs/

Comment: You have two ESP, and Ubuntu/grub boot files in both. The 0001 is in ESP with Windows on NVMe drive, but has some extra text with "Windows"? Your 0003 boots using GUID/partUUID of sda3. And both look like they are configured to boot install in sda4. Your fstab has the ESP on the NVMe drive as default mount for updates. Do you get different errors from each of the UEFI boot menu ubuntu entries? Does Windows boot ok from UEFI menu? Is Windows fast start up off as that sets hibernation flag on all Windows partitions?